# Restore the fragments in a view pager to their initial state

Tags: android, android-fragments

My application has a number of tabs the contents of which are contained in a FragmentStatePagerAdapter. In every tab, user can navigate deeper which means the fragment could change. However, the client wants whenever user navigates to a tab, it should show the initial state of the tab regardless of its previous state. Is there any way that I can achieve that?

Comment: once the fragment is shown, the "onResume" callback should run, use it to put the fragment back to its original state.

Answer (score -1):

try using in adapter:

```
    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
    return POSITION_NONE;
    }
```

Comment: Code-only answers fall under "Low quality"  and are candidates for deletion. Please, improve your answer adding some comments; tell future readers *why* this solution should work.

Comment: adapter by default assumes that there is no item to change so adapter doesn't notify and view is not updated when user comes back again.
You can follow link for more detail http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerAdapter.html#getItemPosition(java.lang.Object)